# spark_apply and resource management

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to determine what memory should be allocated to Spark executors/driver when I use `spark_apply`.

The question boils down to how much memory should be allocated to the driver and executor and how should this be allocated between the spark app/the user memory block/anywhere else?

**An example**

As an example, let's say there is an input spark dataframe containing a vector of 1 billion integers partitioned into 10 equal sized chunks and the function passed to `spark_apply` is then taking each partition and outputting 4 replicas of the input (concatenated end-to-end). Also, let's say the executors have 1 core and the driver performs a `collect` on the resulting spark data frame. I'm also going to ignore system/JVM/R overhead for the time being.

*The executors*

Each input partition is 4 bytes * 1e9 / 10 = 0.4GB. Each output partition is 0.4GB * 4 = 1.6GB.

One thought is that I'll need at least 0.4gb of memory for the input spark object, 0.4gb for the copy of that object in R, 1.6gb for the R data frame result, and 1.6gb for when that object is copied to a resulting spark data frame (i.e. 4gb). However, if neither the Spark input or output are cached, then perhaps I just need 2gb if the Spark data is streamed to R in small bits (i.e. the main memory usage is just the input and output R data frames).

I also presume that the R process takes memory from the "user" memory block (see [here](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/)). If so, under the 4gb case above, the memory should be split 50:50 and in the 0.8gb case one should allocate almost all of it to the user memory block.

*The driver*

As for the executor, depending on how the spark data frame is handled, I may need to have 16GB (if the resulting spark data frame is not cached and the data is streamed into an R object) or 32GB (if the spark data frame is materialised in its entirety before being copied into an R object). With similar considerations for the split between spark and user memory blocks.

Comment: _I also presume that the R process takes memory from the "user" memory block_ - No. Guest language memory usage is not accounted in the JVM heap memory. If you use cluster managers which monitor off-heap memory tracking (YARN, Kubernetess) you have to configure corresponding overhead option. Regarding your calculations I'd say you are far to optimistic. Also if _driver performs a collect on the resulting spark data frame_, and as far as I understand, data is already larger than the input, you're probably choosing a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Regarding the collect on the result, I realise it's stupid but I was just doing something to consider the Driver's needs.

Comment: Also, regarding optimism. Sure, although I'm trying to make the requirements concrete rather than just waving my hands and saying "some more memory for other stuff that I'm not aware of".